# Compute the differential of the endpoint map of a control system

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, optimal-control

I consider a general control system:

$$
\dot{x} = f(t,x, u), \quad x\in \mathbb{R}^n,\ u\in L^{\infty}([0,T], \mathbb{R}^m)
$$

starting at $x(0)=x_0$. Its endpoint map $\mathcal{E}_{T, x_0}:\ L^{\infty}([0,T], \mathbb{R}^m)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by $\mathcal{E}_{T, x_0}(u):=x(T)$, where $x$ satisfies the previous system. I know that its differential is given by:

$$
D\mathcal{E}(u)\cdot v := \int_0^T M(T)M^{-1}(s)B(s)v\ ds
$$

**Question**: is there a way to get the application $D\mathcal{E}(u)$ alone ?

As an example I would be interested by a *numerical* method computing the differential of the endpoint map of the following system:

$$
\dot{x} = y, \quad
\dot{y} = -x-2x^3+u
$$

Comment: What is "alone" in "getting $D\mathcal{E}(u)$ alone"? This is still a map from a function space to a vector, so in the more regular case a vector of $L^1$ functions. How would you see a numerical representation of that?

Comment: I understand your comment. My purpose is to compute the right inverse of $D\mathcal{E}(u)$ via the Moore-Penrose Pseudo inverse. That's why I wanted to get the explicit form of $D\mathcal{E}(u)$.
Do you have a clue how to compute this application directly?